# Densities of stable distributions are smooth?

Tags: probability-distributions

Fix $1<p<2$. Assume that $\mu_p$ is a $p$-stable probability distribution on the real line. That is, a probability measure whose characteristic function is $e^{-|t|^p}$.

The book "Parametric statistical inference" by  James K. Lindsey, says, on page $53$, that ***"stable distributions are continuous, with smooth unimodal densities"***.

I could not find a reference for the fact that the density is smooth. Can someone please point out such a reference? Thank you.

Comment: This is a simple consequence of the inversion formula (pdf from cf) and the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement).

Comment: @Gabriel Romon - I think "smooth" means $C^{\infty}$. Can you prove that the density is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Of course, by repeated applications of the theorem.,

Comment: So you claim that the Fourier transform of $e^{-|t|^p}$ is infinitely differentiable by essentially differentiating under the integral sign. This does not look right to me, because , since $1<p<2$, after three derivatives you get terms that are not locally integrable in a nbd of zero, so you cannot continue differentiating.

Comment: The derivatives of the integrand w.r.t. $x$ have the form $Kt^n\cos(xt)e^{|t|^p}$ or $Kt^n\sin(xt)e^{|t|^p}$. How are they not integrable ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.